# Generating pdf with Jxls

Tags: java, pdf, jakarta-ee

we have a system to generate xlsx file from xlsx templates using jxls, Now we will need to have a pdf output also, I'm wondering about a way to do it, in preference with jxls (poor documented a little), so we won't have to redevelopp. If it's not possible, what's the easiest way to generate such reports from templates also? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate pure pdf, IMHO best choice is [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/), to convert xlsx to pdf - [JODConverter](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/)

Comment: Thank you, I will consider this solution imho.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest iText, this is a very simple & efficient tool.

Comment: Thank you, I've looked at it, but the licence model did not encourage me.